# How to make __missing__ automatically called on __getitem__ KeyError

Tags: python, magic-methods

I'm writing a class that emulates a mapping object.  It has the following functions.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vars = {}

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.vars[key]

    def __missing__(self,key):
        return key
```

I would think that a call to `obj[missing_key]` would also call `__missing__`. But since I've overridden `__getitem__` I have to do this

```
def __getitem__(self,key):
    try:
        return self.vars[key]
    except KeyError as e:
        return self.__missing__(key)
```

It seems that the `__missing__` hook is not wrapped into calls to `__getitem__` but instead built inside `__getitem__`.  This makes the `__missing__` hook only useful for classes that extend dict.  In my case it makes no sense and I should just implement the missing functionality inside the try/except.

Is there a way to make `__getitem__` automatically call `__missing__` on a `KeyError`?

Comment: It looks like it's only applicable on subclasses of dict `If a subclass of dict defines a method __missing__`

Comment: You could just define a mixin class with the desired behavior for ``__getitem__``

Comment: `__missing__` is not a general "what happens when `__getitem__` doesn't work" hook. It's specifically a thing that `dict.__getitem__` looks for, and implementing it only makes sense for `dict` subclasses.

Comment: How do you think a hook for calling `__missing__` could be in calls to the method rather than with the method itself? So, yes, you'll have to implement it yourself in your class's custom `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__):

> `object.__missing__(self, key)`
>
> > Called by `dict.__getitem__()` to implement `self[key]` for dict subclasses when key is not in the dictionary.

Basically, if you're not a `dict` subclass, or you are, but you overloaded `__getitem__` without delegating up the inheritance chain to `dict.__getitem__`, then `__missing__` means nothing, because nothing checks for it. **You can't make it call `__missing__` implicitly unless you're a `dict` subclass.**

If you're writing your own mapping class, and you want it to do something like `__missing__`, you don't really need to have a `__missing__` at all, just put the handling code in your `__getitem__`:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    try:
        return self.var[key]
    except KeyError:
        return key
```

That behaves the way you expected (note: It does not update `self.var`). You could use `dict.get` to shorten it to just:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.var.get(key, key)
```